# Display larger than my external screen

Tags: ati, display, radeon, hdmi, external-monitor

I seem to have this problem every time I install Ubuntu. I have a Panasonic Viera Plasma 50" and the display area on it is always cropped I have tried all kinds of configurations with the terminal (ie...xrandr) I am at a total loss and would like any advice as I am still moderately new to Linux. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My TV is a Panasonic TC-P50X1 (50" plasma), upon installation of Ubuntu 13.04 I connected my HDMI cable to find that Ubuntu did not display correctly ...e.g. display are was larger than my external screen (Panasonic TC-P50X1). This can be fixed (at least in my case for sure) by downloading the ATI binary x.org driver (proprietary) w/Optional add-on via software center. Install, reboot, then navigate via dashboard ("start button" for you Windows familiar persons) software & Updates, then additional drivers, try each of the drivers that you should see following these steps apply changes then reboot if any of them work your screen will display correctly upon reboot. Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Some times the tv processor misinterprets the input signal and changes the aspect/zoom ratio to what it perceives as appropriate. So please try the following on your TV set:

On page 18 of the user manual:

```
> **Change aspect ratio and Zoom the picture**
> 
> Press **FORMAT** to cycle through the aspect modes 
> 
> • 480i, 480p: FULL/JUST/4:3/ ZOOM • 1080p, 1080i, 720p:
> FULL/H-FILL/JUST/4:3/ZOOM Use when the picture does not fill the whole
> screen (bars appears on either side of the image) or portions of the
> picture is trimmed. Note
> 1. Some content, such as film-based movies, are available in extra-wide format. Top and bottom bars are unavailable.
> 2. Connected devices, such as Cable/Satellite box, DVD/Blu-ray players and game consoles have their own aspect (format) settings. Adjust the
> device’s aspect settings
```

On page 50 you will find detailed info on how to cycle through the various modes and how to handle zooming.

Comment: I should have mentioned that while using HDMI cable zoom option is not available, please advise..and thank you for you response

Comment: I found the solution to THIS issue to be fixed by: